# HTML creating space around input text?

Tags: html, css

page is available here: http://macrorevolution.com/calculators/bmr/

How do I go about creating space after my input[text] box. For example, I want to create 1px spacing between the input box and "Years","ft","In"."k/cal per day".

I tried using .ipadding but that didn't work so ignore it. Also, how can I shift all of the input boxes closer to "Age", "Height", "weight"?

I am new to html/css.

```
<?php
$answer = "";
$agev = "";
$feetv = "";
$inchesv = "";
$weightv = "";
$sex = "";
if(isset($_POST['agev']) && isset($_POST['feetv']) && isset($_POST['inchesv']) && isset($_POST['weightv']) && isset($_POST['sex'])) {
    $agev = $_POST['agev'];
    $feetv = $_POST['feetv'];
    $inchesv = $_POST['inchesv'];
    $weightv = $_POST['weightv'];
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    $totalheightv = $inchesv + ($feetv*12);
    $heightcm = $totalheightv*2.54;
    $weightkg = $weightv/2.2;
    if($sex=='male') $answer = round((66.47 + (13.75*$weightkg) + (5*$heightcm) - (6.75*$agev)),0);
    if($sex=='female') $answer = round((665.09 + (9.56*$weightkg) + (1.84*$heightcm) - (4.67*$agev)),0);

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<title>Basal Metabolic Rate Calculator</title>
<style>
  table {
      border: 30px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
  }
tr.spaceUnder > td
{
  padding:0em 1em 1em 0em;

}
p.ss {
    font-size:30px; 
}
.ipadding {
    padding:1px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box pt20">
<p class="ss">MacroRevolution BMR Calculator</p><br>
<table width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan="4">
BMR = Basal Metabolic Rate (similar to RMR = Resting Metabolic Rate). Your BMR represents the number of calories your body burns at rest. Regular routine of cardiovascular exercise can increase your BMR, improving your health and fitness when your body's ability to burn energy gradually slows down.
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form method='post' action=''>
<table width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">


    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td>Age:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='agev' value="<?php echo $agev; ?>"/>Years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td>Height:</td>
        <td align="justify"><input type='text' name='feetv' value="<?php echo $feetv; ?>"/>Ft<p>   </p>

        <input type='text' name='inchesv' value="<?php echo $inchesv; ?>"/>In</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td>Weight:</td>
        <td align="left"><input type='text' name='weightv' value="<?php echo $weightv; ?>"/>lbs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td colspan="2"><input type='radio' name='sex' value='male'>Male
                        <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female'>Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td colspan="2"><input type='submit' class="button highlight small" value='Calculate'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td colspan="2">Your BMR is <input type='text' style="width: 50px;" value='<?php echo $answer?>' />k/cal per day  </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>


<table border='0' width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <td colspan="4">

    Formula for BMR
    If you want to manually calculate your BMR, use the (<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris%E2%80%93Benedict_equation">Harris-Benedict formula</a>) <br> below. <br><br>
Men: BMR=66.47+ (13.75 x W) + (5.0 x H) - (6.75 x A) <br>
Women: BMR=665.09 + (9.56 x W) + (1.84 x H) - (4.67 x A) <br><br>

    W = Weight in kilograms (lbs/2.2)<br>
    H = Height in centimeters (inches x 2.54)<br>
    A = Age in years <br><br><br>
    </td>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

put a margn on the right side.

```
input {
margin-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
input{
margin-right:1px;
}
```

For bringing textboxes near to the label put them in the same td.

### [See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLjtK/2/)

Answer (score 0):

So many ways, one is as:

```
input[type="text"] {margin-right:1px;}
input[type="radio"] {margin-right:5px;}
.spaceUnder td:first-child {width:50px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

just follow the image and create a new css rule and update css rule.Hope it will be helpful!

**Step: 1**

---

[image]

**Step:2**

---

[image]

Comment: How do I edit the style sheet? I am using a wordpress theme so I only know how to access the code I provided which i am uploading as a template

Comment: Hi! Just open the style.css in the directory http://macrorevolution.com/wp-content/themes/balance/style.css and add your style whatever I posted in image at the end of the style.css page